# xpath multiple conditions

Tags: xpath, selenium

In selenium IDE,
I need to find the 3rd link whose text is 'XXX'

```
<tr>
  <td>clickAndWait</td>
  <td>//a[text()='XXX'][3]</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

error: element not found, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered in my comment on [selenium scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816261)

It may be because of a subtlety in XPath where `//a[1]` will select all descendant a elements that are the first para children of their parents, and not the first a element in the entire document. It might work better for you to use something like `//body/descendant::a[1]` or anchor it to an element with an id like `id('myLinks')/descendant::a[1]`. Note that for the last example you would need to proceed the locator with `xpath=`.

Comment: I need to first filter by text though, not id,
locator=text('myLinks')/descendant::a[1] is an invalid xpath, I need to find the nth link whose text is myLinks.  The links can be anywhere in the document.

Comment: I didn't suggest using `locator=text('myLinks')/descendant::a[1]`, which is indeed an invalid XPath. Does my suggestion of `//body/descendant::a[1]` not work?

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

**`(//a[text()='XXX'])[3]`**

The expression:

`//a[text()='XXX'][3]`

selects every `a` element that has some text child with value `'XXX'` and which is the 3rd child of its parent. Obviously, there are no such nodes, and you do not want this but you want the 3-rd from all such `a` elements.

**This is exactly selected by the first XPath expression above**.